# Word guessing game

Tags: code-golf, word, search

A program should take an input on stdin, and guess what a word might be. It should run as a session. One example session is shown below. Characters are fed to it, with a * for a letter not revealed; it should remember letters already revealed. It shows possible words in a list if the total number words found is less than 20, otherwise it shows the count of words.

I recommend `/usr/share/dict/words` on any Linux/Unix for the list of words, or your favourite word list on other platforms.

**Example session (yours may vary):**

```
>>> *****
6697 matches
>>> G****
312 matches
>>> *u***
Trying Gu***
35 matches
>>> Gu**s
Gus's
Guy's
guess
gulfs
gulls
gulps
gum's
gun's
gurus
gusts
gut's
guy's
12 matches
>>> **e**
Trying Gue*s
Is it "guess"?
```

Comment: I did this some years ago in JavaScript, except that it was not golfed and was a *real* Hangman player following the [usual rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangman_%28game%29#Example_game), including guessing only one letter at a time.

Comment: To remove bias due to path lengths, can we assume that the word list is in a file named 'w' in the working directory?

Comment: @peter That would be fine, but make it clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Bash (171)

```
#!/bin/bash
s=`cat /dev/stdin | sed 's/\*/\./g'`;o=`cat /usr/share/dict/words | grep -x $s`;w=`echo "$o" | wc -l`;if [ $w -lt '20' ]; then echo "$o";fi;echo "$w match(es)"
```

Comment: That `cat /dev/stdin |` looks very no-op to me.  Are you sure you need it?

Comment: Similarly, the `cat /usr/share/dict/words |` could probably just turn into an input redirection `</usr/share/dict/words`

Comment: @JB: This was my first entry, so there's probably room for improvement.

Answer (score 2):

### Perl, 170 chars

```
open W,'</usr/share/dict/words';@D=<W>;
while(<>){@W=split//,$w;$w&&s/\*/$W[$-[0]]/ge;y/*/./;$w=$_;
($r=@R=grep/^$w$/i,@D)<20&&map{print}@R;print$r." matches\n";$r<2&&last}
```

Added (not counted) newlines for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

### PHP, 302

```
<?system('stty -icanon');$i=0;$s=explode(PHP_EOL,file_get_contents('/usr/share/dict/words'));while(1){$q.=fread(STDIN,1);system('clear');$x=0;$a='';$i++;for($j=0;$j<count($s);$j++){if(!strncasecmp($q,$s[$j],$i)){$x++;$a.="\n$s[$j]";}}echo str_pad($q,20,'*');echo$x<=20?"\n$a":'';echo"\n$x matches\n";}
```